# The name of this font

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Can you tell me please, the name of this font

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. I think that your question it is off-topic here. However you can find the exact font or knowing where you have taken the photo, or the pdf. file using these links: https://www.whatfontis.com/ and https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ for example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about identifying a font and should be directed elsewhere.